# ffmpeg cannot install PHP extension module

Tags: php, ffmpeg

In the last step of installing FFmpeg-PHP, I had to type `sudo make install`.

At this I get the following error,

```
sudo make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php5/20060613/
cp: cannot stat `modules/*': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

Now my extension directory is at `/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions`

How can I tell this to my machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install PHP extension, you just simply need to copy .so file to your extension directory, and add configuration line.

But in your case, looks like "modules" folder does not exist. This could be because compilation did not go through. Did you get any errors during "./configure && make" stage?

Comment: I did just as you said.. and did not care about the modules folder.. And it works !!