# ffmpeg install error on centos 6

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, ffmpeg-php

Getting this error:

```
[root@web1 ffmpegphp]# make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib64/php/modules/
cp: cannot stat `modules/*': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

It is some what same as: [ffmpeg cannot install PHP extension module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109241/ffmpeg-cannot-install-php-extension-module)

But i could not find ".so" file: [PHP cannot load shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800203/php-cannot-load-shared-libraries)

It's says "PHP extensions are not compiled for this version of your PHP"

My server PHP:

```
[root@web1 ffmpegphp]# phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

How do I change my PHP Api number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ffmpeg cannot install PHP extension module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109241/ffmpeg-cannot-install-php-extension-module)

Comment: it's solved now. changed the ffmpeg-php version and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055252/make-ffmpeg-movie-lo-error-1-when-compiling-ffmpeg-php

Answer (score 0):

**install ffmpeg:**

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

**install FFmpeg-Php**

```
mkdir ffmpegphp
cd ffmpegphp
wget http ://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ffmpeg-php/OldFiles/ffmpeg-php-0.6.2.tbz2
tar jxvf ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2
cd ffmpeg-php-0.6.0
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

If error is encountered:
[make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1 when compiling ffmpeg-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055252/make-ffmpeg-movie-lo-error-1-when-compiling-ffmpeg-php)

If installation completed successfully `ffmpeg.so` file will be created in `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`.

Go to your `php.ini` path (`cd /etc/php.d/` in CentOS 6.7).

Create file `ffmpeg.ini` and add `extension=ffmpeg.so`.

**Restart httpd**

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

**Note: change version if it's getting error or install ffmpeg-devel**

**Source:**

- http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm
- https://chrisjean.com/install-ffmpeg-and-ffmpeg-php-on-centos-easily/